# why show always last value of arraylist in listview?

Tags: android

I have start a timer which call getMessage webservice which return comming  message for that user arraylist size always show right number of messages but when show in list view of that message show only last message send give by web service I have use this code.

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        if(msg.arg1!=RECIEVEFAILURE)
           {
            objrReceiveMessageSiteList =(ArrayList<ReceiveMessageSiteList>)msg.obj;
            System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus());
            System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size());
            if(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size()!=0 && !objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("No New Message"))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size();i++)
                {
                    objkeyvaluepair.setMessage(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessage());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setMessageType(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessageType());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setTimeStamp(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getTimeStamp());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setSenderFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderFirstName());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setSenderId(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderId());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setRecieverFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getReceiverFirstName());
                    messagerecord.add(objkeyvaluepair);
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE SIZE"+messagerecord.size());
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE---------- findeee"+messagerecord.get(i).getMessage());

                }
                System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)--------------"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus());
                message.setText(""+messagerecord.size());
            }
    }

    }
};
```

inside this for loop arraylist is showing right message in syste.out.println.but when sending in adapter set adapter take right size but show only last message in all list view.please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this method to the following:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        if(msg.arg1!=RECIEVEFAILURE)
           {
            objrReceiveMessageSiteList =(ArrayList<ReceiveMessageSiteList>)msg.obj;
            System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus());
            System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size());
            if(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size()!=0 && !objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("No New Message"))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size();i++)
                {
                    //Create Local object of the Objkeyvaluepair here, for example
                    //ObjectKeyValuePair objkeyvaluePair=new OjectKeyvaluePair();
                    objkeyvaluepair.setMessage(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessage());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setMessageType(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessageType());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setTimeStamp(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getTimeStamp());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setSenderFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderFirstName());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setSenderId(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderId());
                    objkeyvaluepair.setRecieverFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getReceiverFirstName());
                    messagerecord.add(objkeyvaluepair);
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE SIZE"+messagerecord.size());
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE---------- findeee"+messagerecord.get(i).getMessage());

                }
                System.out.println("objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0)--------------"+objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(0).getMessageStatus());
                message.setText(""+messagerecord.size());
            }
    }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same object (`objkeyvaluepair`) to the `ArrayList` each iteration through the nested `for` loops.

In the inner-most `for` loop, you should be creating a new `objkeyvaluepair` object and then add this new object to the `ArrayList`.